# Directories like Desktop,Documents,Downloads not created under user's directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I executed the below given command

sudo adduser test1

It is creating the directory for test1 user but the directory is empty.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use useradd command instead of adduser. Also, check the skel file in /etc/.

Answer (score 0):

Try `useradd` command instead of `adduser` as both the commands has same meaning in different versions of linux.

So if one not works the other will work for sure or bth of them